# GTM Cleanup tag with conditions

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Is it possible to sequence tags in Google Tag Manager this way?

**Tag A :** This tag fires with specific trigger when needed. All cool.

**Tag B :** It is set up as a cleanup tag firing after Tag A, but I'd like to add some conditions to it as if it was a trigger. Literally "fire TAg B after Tag A WHEN some coditions are true". Making it a condition-operated cleanup tag.

Does GTM support anything like that? If not through setting it as a cleanup tag, is there any workaround to achieve similar behaviour?

**EDIT 1 More details:**
What is even more specific about this situation is that I can not just push something into DL and condition Tag B for that variable because:

1. Event that interests me (for Tag B) fires organically on the page first
2. Then response event (for Tag A) comes second almost right after.
3. I want to fire a Tag based on event type and other data from first event and collect some other data from second event

Comment: I once experiment with attached a setup tag to the cleanup tag (in addition to the preceeding tag in the sequence)  that had certain trigger exceptions set, with the setting that the following tag should only fire when the setup tags fires. This seemed to work at the time, but the cross-dependencies caused a lot of headache (even describing this concisely is almost impossible). It's easier to use a Custom HTML tag as cleanup tag and test your conditions with a few "ifs" (feels kind of wrong, though - not very tagmanager-ish).

Comment: Wow, thanks, I don't know why didn't I think of that earlier. I'm trying to implement a solution which saves values from two events ago, and previous event too. Then adding universal event that fires every time something happens and checking for these values. But exactly as you said, it causes a lot of headache and doesn't seem that reliable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked in the end is this:

1. Creating **Trigger 1** firing an **Event 1**, basically every time (when at specific URL and its variations)
2. **Event 1** pushes data into DataLayer. Actual data in the DL at the time of the **Event 1** go to my custom *eventTypePrevious* section of DL and "previous data" go even deeper to *eventTypePreviousTwoEventsAgo*. This way I am aware of important data from 2 recent past events.

An example how could it look like:

```
{{DL core eventType}} is DataLayer variable eventType

window.dataLayer.push({
          eventTypePreviousTwoEventsAgo: {{DL eventTypePrevious}}
          eventTypePrevious : {{DL core eventType}},
      });
}
```

3. I created another trigger **Delayed Trigger** which fires only when conditions are met. Meaning I check for data from **eventTypePreviousTwoEventsAgo** and **eventTypePrevious** and if it is the required sequence I fire my desired **Event 2** which has access to everything needed nicely prepared in DL.

This solution needs no tag sequencing, which probably wouldn't work in my case, no HTML snippet hacks and seems kind-of-ok to me.

I'm still interested if anyone had similar problem and how did they solve it. I'm marking this as an answer for now and posting it in here to be of help potentially.